# why can't you simply evaluate QCD processes in a high kin energy frame

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

Asymptotic freedom says that QCD coupling becomes weak at high energies, right? Why can't you simply shift to a frame where our given particles have high kinetic energy, evaluate the process with weak coupling, and shift back to the lab frame?

Comment: Roughly, what matters is the momentum transfer, so just boosting the system does not help. Clearly, computing the mass of a moving proton cannot be any easier than computing the mass of a proton at rest.

Comment: Something that may be of interest here is "lattice QCD in the infinite momentum frame" (also sometime "on the light cone") which was a hot subfield in the late 1990s at least. Don't know what has happened to it since then (a grad school office mate was working on it...). I don't think the win was getting to use the weak coupling regimes, but rather mixing the time and space coordinates in way that allowed you to do the computations at lower dimensionality. Or something.